# MSSQL Monitoring tool

Tags: sql-server-2008, monitoring, performance-testing

I want to measure the database performance tool to identify which query is running long time, CPU utilisation and how many active connection being used.I am using MSSQL(SQL server 2008). Also I want to generate report from tool.

please help me.

Comment: You should try another Stack Exchange site. Either http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/. Stack Overflow is the wrong place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in reports which helps ..

1.Right click on server -->reports-->standard reports..

[image]

2.If you want further customization,you can use [Glenn Berry DMV's](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/category/dmv-queries/) and generate reports out of them..

3.You also can check out [SQLSentry products](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products) which we use in our company as well

4.One more option is to use [stackoverflow Opserver](https://github.com/opserver/Opserver) which is open source

Answer (score 0):

You can used activity monitor.

Right click on server 
-->Activity Monitor.

Yo can check in Processess,Resource Waits,Data file I/O,Recent Expensive Queries.
[image]